# converting Japanese text to speech using python APO

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-speech-api

I need to convert my Japanese sentences into audio files and save them separately. I have found the [gtts](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/convert-text-to-speech-in-python) package that can do this with English and some other languages. But it seems Japanese is not supported.

Is there any alternative way for Japanese?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Asking for libraries and tools is off topic. [This](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) seems tsupport japanese and it has a rest interface as well as a pip package https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there's a program in BASH that does text-to-speech.
`sudo apt install translate-shell`  https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell

```
trans -p -lang ja "hello"
```

I only mention that, because you could call it with a subprocess, if need be.

---

---

The one you mentioned seems to run fine though.  https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/convert-text-to-speech-in-python

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

##  sudo apt install ffmpeg espeak libespeak1 python-gst-1.0
##  pip3 install gTTS pyttsx3 playsound

import gtts
from playsound import playsound

tts = gtts .gTTS( '感嘆詞', lang='ja' )  ##  request google to get synthesis

tts .save( 'hello.mp3' )  ##  save audio
playsound( 'hello.mp3' )  ##  play audio

##  print( gtts .lang .tts_langs() )
```